# Is it possible to pass queryFn to useQuery?

Tags: javascript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

As stupid as it sounds, my queryFn is taken from the context:

```js
const fetch = useAppFetch()
```

I can't change this for historical reasons, so I'm wondering if it's possible to pass in queryFn when using it?

```js
const fetch = useAppFetch()
const { data } = useDynamicQuery(
  { ...args },
  { queryFn: React.useCallback((args) => fetch(args), [fetch]) }
})
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @Philisonstrike Yes, I've tried passing queryFn as a parameter, but I get a warning: "A non-serializable value was detected in the state" , which works, but doesn't seem to be the recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bizarre design pattern but sometimes we've got to make things work.

It seems like you figured out the implementation, based on your comment:

> @Philisonstrike Yes, I've tried passing queryFn as a parameter, but I get a warning: "A non-serializable value was detected in the state" , which works, but doesn't seem to be the recommended way.

What I'm not understanding is how you are getting a non-serializable value in your **state**.  You will inevitably have a non-serializable value in your action but that's not a problem (it's solved by `thunk` middleware).

Are you are storing the `queryFn` argument in the state somehow?  The [default implementation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/dd4b36a41d6b68bcd52058cdabf4acf903c32841/packages/toolkit/src/query/defaultSerializeQueryArgs.ts#L3) of the [`serializeQueryArgs`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs) API option should have handled removing it.  The only way I can imagine this being the cause is if you're already setting your own `serializeQueryArgs` option and it's not serializing everything.

It seems more likely that the `queryFn` itself is returning its data in a non-serializable format.  In which case your bizarre setup it's really the culprit.

You need to track down the details of where and what this non-serializable value is and go from there.

You haven't shown your implementation so I don't know what issues might be occurring there.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't describe clearly enough, I feel sorry, I made a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-david-5d7rzv?file=/src/index.js

Comment: The full error message is: A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `api.queries.getTodoById({"todoId":"123"}).originalArgs.queryFn`

Comment: ahhh right, the `originalArgs`!  I have to think about this.  I'm not sure if `serializeQueryArgs` would modify the `originalArgs` or just the stringified query cache key.

Comment: When I first read you question I was thinking about the `originalArgs` and thinking it was simple and you just needed to use `serializeQueryArgs` to strip the `queryFn` out of the args.  But then I started looking at the docs and source for `serializeQueryArgs` and realized that in spite of the name, it only impacts the query cache key.

Comment: This is definitely an inadvisable design pattern but I'm always curious whether something can technically work.  And I understand the problem because the API endpoint definition is outside of React and can't access React context.

Comment: You can do something smarter if you are able to modify your `useAppFetch()` hook and if the difference in behaviors can be represented by some serializable arguments, like a `string` `baseUrl`, `boolean` `setAuthHeaders`, etc.  Have a hook based on React context that returns those arguments rather than returning a `fetch` function.  Pass that data in the arguments when calling your RTK hook.  Then your `baseQuery` is responsible for executing the correct fetch based on those arguments.

Comment: I can't modify useAppFetch, this project is too big, I finally decided to copy the code of useAppFetch and rewrite it into useAppContext, it was a bit of a pain, but finally solved this problem, I hope I can finally delete useAppFetch completely